# View row values in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

In the csv module in python, there is a function called `csv.reader` which allows you to iterate over a row, returns a reader object and can be held in a container like a list.

So when the list assigned to a variable and is printed, ie:

```
csv_rows = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'))
print (csv_rows)
>
>
>
[['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Zodicac', 'Date of birth', 'Sex'] # I gave an example of the function outputting a header row
```

So far, I don't see a similar function like this in the openpyxl. I could be mistaken so I'm wondering if any of you can help me out.

**Update**

@alecxe, your solution works perfectly (except its casting my date of birth as a datetime format instead of a regular string).

```
def iter_rows(ws):
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    yield [cell.value for cell in row]
>
>
>>> pprint(list(iter_rows(ws)))
[['First Nam', 'Last Name', 'Zodicac', 'Date of birth', 'Sex'], ['John', 'Smith', 'Snake', datetime.datetime(1989, 9, 4, 0, 0), 'M']]
```

Since I'm a beginner I wanted to know how this would work if I used a for loop instead of a list comprehension.

So I used this:

```
def iter_rows(ws):
result=[]
for row in ws.iter_rows()
    for cell in row:
        result.append(cell.value)
yield result
```

It *almost* gives me the exact same output, instead it gives me this:
As you can tell, it essentially gives me one gigantic list instead of nested list in the result you gave me.

```
>>>print(list(iter_rows(ws)))

[['First Nam', 'Last Name', 'Zodicac', 'Date of birth', 'Sex', 'David', 'Yao', 'Snake', datetime.datetime(1989, 9, 4, 0, 0), 'M']]
```

Comment: If something works with a list comprehension then it will also work with a list. The difference between the two is that the list comprehension creates a list for each row in the worksheet. If you want to do this in your solution you'll need to create a new list for each row and append this to result. There is no reason, however,  not to use a list comprehension to do this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`iter_rows()`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows) has probably a similar sense:

> Returns a squared range based on the range_string parameter, using
>   generators. If no range is passed, will iterate over all cells in the
>   worksheet

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> 
>>> wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
>>> ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
>>> 
>>> pprint(list(ws.iter_rows()))
[(<Cell Sheet1.A1>,
  <Cell Sheet1.B1>,
  <Cell Sheet1.C1>,
  <Cell Sheet1.D1>,
  <Cell Sheet1.E1>),
 (<Cell Sheet1.A2>,
  <Cell Sheet1.B2>,
  <Cell Sheet1.C2>,
  <Cell Sheet1.D2>,
  <Cell Sheet1.E2>),
 (<Cell Sheet1.A3>,
  <Cell Sheet1.B3>,
  <Cell Sheet1.C3>,
  <Cell Sheet1.D3>,
  <Cell Sheet1.E3>)]
```

---

You can modify it a little bit to yield a list of row values, for example:

```
def iter_rows(ws):
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        yield [cell.value for cell in row]
```

Demo:

```
>>> pprint(list(iter_rows(ws)))
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, None, None],
 [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, None, None],
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, None, None]]
```

Comment: Humbled by your presence alecxe. :) Great answer as always. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, is there any way to do convert that list comprehension into a for loop? (just fmi) So far, appending each cell value it to a empty list, then `yield` the list doesn't give me the same result as your solution

Comment: @bLunt thank you for the kind words and an interesting question. Just want to clarify the following. What is your desired result and what result are you getting currently?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll go ahead and update/edit the original post I made above.

Comment: Alright, OP is updated for your review. I'm off to bed, I will check your response sometime tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: @bLunt thanks, you can try out `internal_value` instead of `value`. Going AFK too, let's continue tomorrow.

Comment: @alecxe - Can you demonstrate with cell_range = ws['B2:D3']?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work using this method:

```
all_rows = []

for row in worksheet:
    current_row = []
    for cell in row:
        current_row.append(cell.value)
    all_rows.append(current_row)
```

Essentially, I created a list for all of the data.
Then, I iterated through each row in the worksheet.
Each `cell.value` within a row was added to a short-term list (current row).
Once all of the `cell.values` within the row are added to the short-term list, the short-term list is added to the long-term list.

Answer (score 2):

After loading the workbook using your specified file path and choosing a worksheet, you may use a list comprehension for gathering each row by using `ws.iter_rows` and supplying it with the value of `values_only=True`, which will return a tuple for each row of the Excel file containing the ***values*** for each cell. This tuple can then be converted to a list, ultimately returning a two-dimensional list.

```
import openpyxl as opxl

# load the workbook
wb = opxl.load_workbook(file_path)
# choose the worksheet from the excel file
# you may choose the currently active sheet
ws = wb.active
# you may choose to specify a sheet
ws = wb["example_sheet"]

# return a list of lists, each sub list within the
# 2-dimensional list being a record from within the excel file.
return [list(r) for r in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True)]
```

My example was some code I used for ***dealing with Excel files***, ***not CSV***, but perhaps the process may be similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

os.chdir('C:/Users/Eswar_pc/Downloads')
wb = load_workbook('Synonyms.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
corpus = []
e = sheet.iter_rows()
cells = list(e)
for i in cells:
    corpus.append(i[0].value)
print(corpus[1:30])
```

Comment: adding a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your answer so there is an explanation as to why the code works. This will help the OP and any future visitors so they can judge whether this solution is relevant to them. Include any expected output, possible issues and where they may have gone wrong.